# ImportError: cannot import name 'Process'

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am writing a simple program to check how multiprocessing works in Python 3. And I am testing with code that is similar to what is available in Python 3.6 documentation.

However when running the code I am facing an ImportError and not able to move forward.

I have also observed some confusing outputs.
When executing the code in PYthon IDE, it does not throw an error.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
```

However, if i execute it on Linux prompt, it throws an error.

My complete code is

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def worker():
    print("working")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    p = Process(target=worker)
    jobs.append(p)
    p.start()
    print(jobs)


Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/AASRITHA/PycharmProjects/untitled/multiprocessing.py", line 1, in <module>
 from multiprocessing import Process
  File "C:\Users\AASRITHA\PycharmProjects\untitled\multiprocessing.py", line 1, in <module>
  from multiprocessing import Process
 ImportError: cannot import name 'Process'
```

Comment: Rename your file to anything BUT `multiprocessing`

Comment: okay that worked. Thanks inspectorG4dget

Comment: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)